# Cant send data over RTC data channel using simple peer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, arraybuffer, simple-peer

I recently tried implementing p2p file transfer using Webrtc by splitting large files into array buffers and then sending them over the data channel. The code was working a month ago, but now it is suddenly throwing me this error.

```
Uncaught RTCError: Failure to send data 
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
```

Here's the code snippet to send the file.

```
    function sendFile() {
    const peer = peerRef.current;
    const stream = file.stream();
    const reader = stream.getReader();

    reader.read().then(obj => {
        handlereading(obj.done, obj.value);
    });

    function handlereading(done, value) {
        if (done) {
            console.log("done");
            peer.write(JSON.stringify({ done: true, fileName: file.name }));
            return;
        }

        peer.write(value);
        reader.read().then(obj => {
            handlereading(obj.done, obj.value);
            console.log("yolo");
        })
    }

}
```

The code works fine on other browsers like firefox or the mobile Samsung browser.

You can also check my main repo [here](https://github.com/veghfile/Frontend/blob/master/src/context/Maincontext.js) and live app [here](http://vegh.openode.io/) (to reproduce the error)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Did you solve it?